# nodejs functions with callback vs functions without callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following functions file:

```
module.exports = {
   function1: functions(parm1, callback){
       if (checkParm1) {
           //do something
       }else{
           //do something else
       }
       callback();
   }
};
```

Inside this `function1` I want to create a function that holds only a small piece of code. Something like a js simple function:

```
function checkParm1(parm1){
    return ( parm1 === 'abc' );
}
```

Although once I declare `checkParm1` function inside `module.exports` I get the following error:

```
function checkParm1(parm1){
         ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How can I define such a function and use it accross several functions?

Comment: You don't define it inside `module.exports` you define it outside

Comment: Also, `functions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define it outside, you'll still have access to it because of function hoisting:

```
module.exports = {
   function1: functions(parm1, callback){
       if (checkParm1(parm1)) {
           //do something
       }else{
           //do something else
       }
       callback();
   }
};

function checkParm1(parm1){
    return ( parm1 === 'abc' );
}
```

Because `module.exports` is set to an object, you can't place `checkParm1` inside of that object. Instead just define it after the exported object and it will be hoisted to be able to be used within `function1`

Also, the function doesn't need to be hoisted you could also use a function expression above the `module.exports`

Comment: I've upvoted, but the main problem is OP trying to declare the function in the object literal, it doesn't have to be after the `module.exports` is can be before so the section about hoisting is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @Andrew Kim But doing so checkParm1 is not recognized inside function1..  if checkParm1(parm1){
^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: You need to do `if(checkParm1(parm1))`, you're missing the brackets